# How to query DynamoDB and return the first matching result instead of querying the whole collection?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

We have some old code that is doing a query of the DynamoDB to find list of matching records.

Sample code below:

```
    final DynamoDBQueryExpression<MyObject> queryExp = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<MyObject>()
            .withHashKeyValues(myObject)
            .withIndexName(indexName)
            .withScanIndexForward(false)
            .withConsistentRead(true)
            .withLimit(rowsPerPage);
    final PaginatedQueryList<MyObject> ruleInstanceList = dynamoDBMapper.query(MyObject.class, queryExp);
```

This is a slow operation since this query will return a list of matching `MyObject`, and I noticed all we used it for is to check if this list is empty or not.

So what I want to do is simply doing the query to find the first element or even a different type of query to simply make sure the count is greater than 0, all I need to verify is that the record exist so that I can reduce the latency.

My question is, how do I do it in order to achieve this?

Comment: You could presumably just set `withLimit(1)`.

Comment: @jarmod I don't think that's how `Limit` works, I tested it the results is still a complete list

Comment: That doesn't sound right. A single API call with Limit=1 should return at most 1 item.

Comment: @jarmod maybe it's due to the way the code currently being written, but the result is still the complete list instead of just 1. I tested it when `withLimit(1)`

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [getLimit()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBQueryExpression.html#setLimit-java.lang.Integer-) indicates:

> Note that when calling DynamoDBMapper.query, multiple requests are made to DynamoDB if needed to retrieve the entire result set. Setting this will limit the number of items retrieved by each request, NOT the total number of results that will be retrieved. Use DynamoDBMapper.queryPage to retrieve a single page of items from DynamoDB.

To limit the number of results, you can use [queryPage()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.html#queryPage-java.lang.Class-com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBQueryExpression-com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperConfig-) instead of query(). And apply `withLimit(1)` to your query expression.